# How to get value for a input button using jquery?

Tags: jquery, get

I need to retrieve a value for a clickable button using jquery. I have 3 buttons under a `<div>`:

```
<div class="button1">
        <input type="button" value="one" id="One" onclick= "location.href='index.html'"/> 
        <input type="button" value="two" id="Two" onclick="location.href='index.html'" />
        <input type="button" value="three" id="Three" onclick="location.href='index.html'" />
 </div>
```

If I click on button 1, I need to get value for a button 1. I don't know, how exactly get the value of this.

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button1').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $("input").val(text);
        });
});
```

I know this script I wrote is wrong, because I am getting values as "one,two,three".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Like any other input, to get the value of a button use .val():

```
$('input:button').click(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3QDM5/

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with your script though!

Answer (score 4):

use attr 
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#button1').click(function() { 
        var text = $(this).attr('value'); 
        $("#input").val(text); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

example :

```
<input type="button" value="one" id="One" onclick= "click(this.value)'"/>
```

where **click(this.value)** is function on javascript

```
function click(x)
{
    //x is value from onclick button
}
```