# trying to capture which button is selected in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to capture which button is clicked by the user for a simple trivia game. My code seems to break right after the New Game Button function. When I `console.log(userInput)` nothing shows up after clicking the corresponding button. How can I store the value of the button clicked in the variable `userInput`?

```
<div class="gameInfo">
  <div class="timeRemaining"></div>
  <div class="question">question</div>
  <div class="answers">
    <button id="button1" value="Number 1">Button 1</button><br>
    <button id="button2" value="Number 2">Button 2</button><br>
    <button id="button3" value="Number 3">Button 3</button><br>
    <button id="button4" value="Number 4">Button 4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
  $("#newGameButton").click(function() {
    alert("You started a new game!");
    $("#newGameButton").hide();
    $(".gameInfo").show();
    $(".results").show();
    askQuestions();
    assignButtons();
  })

  $("#button1", "#button2", "#button3", "#button4").click(function() {
    var userInput = $(this).val();
    console.log(userInput);
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML to the question please?

Comment: @peeebeee if the buttons are `<button>` or `<input type="button">` the value works just fine.

Comment: I found a question pretty similar to yours, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721178/get-value-for-a-input-button-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handling multiple ids in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604099/handling-multiple-ids-in-jquery)

Comment: @MichaelHurley just added it

Answer (score 4):

Your selector is invalid. It looks like you're attempting to add *all* the `#buttonN` elements in to a single jQuery object, in which case you need to provide a *single* string to the jQuery object, like this:

```js
$("#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4").click(function() {
  var userInput = $(this).val();
  console.log(userInput);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1" value="Number 1">#1</button>
<button id="button2" value="Number 2">#2</button>
<button id="button3" value="Number 3">#3</button>
<button id="button4" value="Number 4">#4</button>
```

You should however note that a common class would make this selector better as it's more extensible.